# SUM 2 values in mysql to make leaderboard

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want make a leaderboard from my database, I already make a code but the sql says error

```
"SET @a1 = (SELECT SUM(d.poin_diskusi)
                FROM diskusi d
                GROUP BY d.id_akun)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"
```

**heres my sql query :**

```
SET @a1 = (SELECT SUM(d.poin_diskusi)
                FROM diskusi d
                GROUP BY d.id_akun);
SET @a2 = (SELECT SUM(j.nilai_jawaban)
                FROM jawaban j
                GROUP BY j.id_akun);
          
SET @hasil = @a1 + @a2;
SELECT @hasil
```

Thank you !
this is an example data in table jawaban:

[image]

this is an example data in table diskusi:

[image]

and my desired answer:

where tera123 have 135 TOTAL(d.poin_diskusi+j.nilai_jawaban) and david123 have 90 TOTAL(d.poin_diskusi+j.nilai_jawaban)
the point is to show TOTAL for every user

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results,

Comment: what part of error message is unclear?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just added it sir

Comment: stop using SET and just do a SELECT query; doing SET and then selecting that variable restricts you to only allowing one result

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me (without looking at your images; if you want to show information, please provide it in text) like you want something like:

```
select id_akun, sum(point_value) as total_points from (
    select id_akun, sum(poin_diskusi) as point_value
    from diskusi group by id_akun
    union all
    select id_akun, sum(nilai_jawaban) as point_value
    from jawaban group by id_akun
) as point_values
group by id_akun
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the `GROUP BY` keywords. Inside the images you provided with example data, one can see that there are multiple entries for the columns `jawaban.id_akun` and `diskusi.id_akun`. Because of that, both `SELECT` will return multiple rows as result, for each different value of the id columns one summed up row. Try it without the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: sorry sir the Group by clause is for the result of every user, without it the result will sum all value in j.nilai_jawaban and d.poin_diskusi. i need it for every user, is there any other option to show multiple row in subquery ? thanks

Comment: Ok, I see. Then I guess a WHERE clause is missing to get just a single result for both  `@a1` and `@a2`. Something like SELECT SUM(...) from ... where id_akun=... group by... And that for all players you have.

Comment: if i use where id_akun the result is for specific user/akun, the sql result should be like this

*TOTAL      *id_akun
200              ilham123
135              tera123
90                david123

Comment: Hm... I think you are looking forward to something like this: `SELECT sum(points), cname from (
SELECT SUM(d.poin_diskusi) points, id_akun FROM diskusi d GROUP_BY d.id_akun
UNION
SELECT SUM(j.nilai_jawaban) points, id_akun FROM jawaban j GROUP_BY j.id_akun)
combinedPoints GROUP_BY combinedPoints.cname;` Maybe you can play a bit around and modify this example if it still not fit your needs.

Comment: @Stibb84 you almost always want UNION ALL, not UNION DISTINCT (which unfortunately is the default); as you show it in your comment, if an id_akun has the same number of points in both tables, it will only count one table.

Comment: @ysth Yes correct, thank you for your addition.